# Get Random item using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Just starting learning about ajax requests using jQuery. I've tried looking at other posts on this but not sure how to implement it. Here's the code I have. Right now it's just getting the first 3 items. I want it to get 3 random items from the rss feed it's pulling. Here's what I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://thrive.local/wp-content/themes/thriveafrica/fetcher.php",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(d) {
                $('item', d).slice(0, 3).each(function() {
                    var $item = $(this);
                    var title = $item.find('title').text();
                    var link = $item.find('link').text();
                    var description = $item.find('description').text();
                    var image = $(description).find('img').attr('src');
                    var price = $(description).find('span.SalePrice').text();
                    if (price == '') {price = 'Visit Store for Price'};

                    var html = '<li><a href="'+link+'" target="_blank">';
                    html += '<div class="image"><img src="'+image+'"></div>';
                    html += '<div class="info"><strong>'+title+'</strong><br/>'+price+'</div>';
                    html += '</a></li>';

                    // Example Output
                    // <li>
                // <div class="image"><img src="http://www.thriveafricastore.com/product_images/s/041/coffee__59525_thumb.jpg"></div>
                // <div class="info"><strong>Thrive Africa Blend (1lb)</strong><br>See Price</div>
              // </li>


                    $('div#store ul').append($(html));
                }); //End Each
        } //End Success
    }); // End Ajax Request
});
```

What are my options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the [shuffle-plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/shuffle) to shuffle your array. the code would be something like:

```
var myresults = $('item', d).shuffle();
myresults.slice(0, 3).each(function() {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd use something like [*filter()*](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), rather than *slice()*, after generating 3 unique numbers in your range:

```
var rnd1, rnd2, rnd3, undef,
    items = $('item', d);

// Generate our random numbers:
rnd1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length);
while (rnd2 == undef || rnd2 == rnd1)
    rnd2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length);
while (rnd3 == undef || rnd3 == rnd1 || rnd3 == rnd2)
    rnd3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length);

//filter our items, only the ones whose index matches one of our randoms:
items.filter(function (index) { 
    return index == rnd1 || index == rnd2 || index == rnd3;
}).each(function {
    // rest of code...
});
```

Be warned that this would stick in an infinite loop if the number of items returned is less than 3, because it generates 3 unique numbers within the range *0 - items length*.  You could take away the while loops and just generate 3 non-unique randoms if this was a possibility.

Here's an example that removes 3 divs at random using this code:  **http://jsfiddle.net/dAjAt/**.   Keep clicking the **Run** button to see it in action.

Answer (score 1):

**If you only want 3 items, your server should only return 3 items.**

Non-the-less, if you want to achieve this with JavaScript:

```
jQuery.fn.random = function (amount) {
  var els = this.get();
  var ret = [];

  while (els.length && ret.length < amount) {
    ret.push(els.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * els.length), 1)[0]);
  }

  return $(ret);
}
```

Then instead of using `$('item', d).slice(0, 3).each`, simply use `$('item', d).random(3).each`